# How to write a java client-server that sends byte arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sockets, byte

I have a good understanding of how java Sockets work. I have made many client - server applications that just send plain text. However, I was wondering how I would make a client - server relationship that were able to send byte arrays back and forward. I'm making a file sharing program (I already have the file loaded in a byte array) You see my current program only accepts the client and sends a file. No communication. I want the client and server to be able to keep a connection and transmit data between the two. For example:

*Client: I want x file

*Server: Okay...

*Server: *Sends x file*

*Client: Gets file

*repeat...

Here is my current code

Client:

```
package Main;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class TransferClient {

    public static void main (String [] args ) throws IOException {
        int filesize = 500 * 1024 * 1024;
        int bytesRead;
        int currentTot = 0;
        Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.11",15123);//127.0.0.1
        byte[] bytearray = new byte [filesize];
        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("copy.mp4"); 
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos); 
        bytesRead = is.read(bytearray,0,bytearray.length);
        currentTot = bytesRead;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Waiting for file... "+start);

        do{
            bytesRead = is.read(bytearray,currentTot,(bytearray.length-currentTot));
            if(bytesRead >= 0){currentTot += bytesRead;}
        } while(bytesRead > -1);
        bos.write(bytearray, 0, currentTot);
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
        socket.close();
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;System.out.println("Got file "+end);
    }

}
```

Server:

```
package Main;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class TransferServer {
    public static void main (String [] args ) throws IOException { 
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(15123); 

        while(true){
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept(); 
            System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + socket); 
            File transferFile = new File ("send.mp4"); 
            byte [] bytearray = new byte [(int)transferFile.length()]; 
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(transferFile); 
            BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin); 
            bin.read(bytearray,0,bytearray.length); 
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream(); 
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("File Size: "+ bytearray.length);
            System.out.println("Sending Files..."); 
            os.write(bytearray,0,bytearray.length); 
            os.flush(); 
            socket.close(); 
            long totalTime  = (System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime)/1000;
            long mbps = (bytearray.length / 1024 /1024) / (totalTime+1);
            System.out.println("File transfer complete : "+totalTime+"/s" + " | Speed: "+mbps+"/mbps");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: How would a loop this code so I can constantly send and receive byte packets?